# Facing issue with ng2-image-upload. Error while compiling the app

Tags: angular, ng2-image-upload

I have been using this library (https://aberezkin.github.io/ng2-image-upload) for some time now. This is the first time I have faced this issue.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular2-image-upload/src/image-upload/image-upload.component.ts
Module build failed: Error: D:\app\node_modules\angular2-image-upload\src\image-upload\image-upload.component.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or
'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview).
at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (D:\app\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:662:23)
at plugin.done.then (D:\app\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
at 
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
@ ./src/app/components/event.component.ts 22:31-103
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

How to resolve it?

app.module.ts

```
import { ImageUploadModule } from 'angular2-image-upload';
@NgModule({
....
imports: [
        ...,
        ImageUploadModule.forRoot()
]
...
})
```

event.component.html

```
<image-upload [max]="10" [uploadedFiles]="home.images"
                                                                  (removed)="onImageRemoved($event)"
                                                                  [extensions]="['jpeg','jpg','png']"
                                                                  (beforeUpload)="imageCheck($event)"
                                                                  (uploadFinished)="onImageUploadFinished($event)"
                                                                    [maxFileSize]="2097152"
                                                                    [fileTooLargeMessage]="'An image was too large and was not uploaded. The maximum file size is 2 Mb.'">
                                                    </image-upload>
```

event.component.ts

```
import {FileHolder} from 'angular2-image-upload/src/image-upload/image-upload.component';
```

Comment: can you share your code? It would be even better if you can create a example that reproduces this error.

Comment: added the part of code req

Comment: there is no need to show code by looking at this there is some installation problem of 3rd party lib. follow the step while adding library import files properly in your module.ts file as well before starting use npm install once again.

Comment: followed the instructions. have been using this library from some time now

Comment: do you have any module.ts file except app.module.ts? also, you need to import the same thing in your component.ts file too.

Comment: No i do not have any other module.ts file. Added the component.ts as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it changed the component.ts to -

```
import {FileHolder} from 'angular2-image-upload';
```